# Flutter making box inside box

Tags: flutter

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL7V2.png)

How can I make a box inside box like in the picture?  when I tried make grey box and giving `with` but It takes all with it can.

> ```
> return ListView(
> physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
>                     parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
> Children:[
> Container(Here is black box),
> Container(Here is Grey box),
> Container(Here is badges),
> ],
> );
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Stack` & `Positioned` widget that helps to put the widgets where ever you want inside the stack.

Hopefully this can help you.